# Is there a formula to find shortest length required to achieve uniqueness across a set

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, formula, array-formulas

I'd like to be able to calculate the length of the shortest sub-string required to achieve complete uniqueness.

Lets say I have a varying length list of 32 character UUIDs, but what I'd like to achieve is shortenening them during reference to only be as long as is required to achieve uniqueness in their set. For instance, if I have the following set of UUID's (pipes inserted to illustrate the answer)...

```
428|07082e1f445e79501bebfa87396af 
723|0785bffaf4747865c202dd0924c7f
b65|634be909d4e5590aa0cdc97251eef
3c4|d94c683624d75a273e3186ec65b78
09e|bd42af0404bcf90413e11c5b40fbb
011|004743d65466dae8a9a6bc814ef4b
1f1|889e04e3a453fbf57521de0a70b60
1ac|44707af8d4681875171ad47c61037
42f|7a6236deb4a9ead32ab2e816d73a3
83a|fe22086064eec87704127622b8165
```

I would only require the first *three* characters to achieve the same level of  uniqueness as if I had used the full 32 character strings.

I'm curious if there is a formula for reaching that value.  I know that I could put this in a couple nested loops, but I'd like to know if there is a more elegant or programmatic way of achieving this.

---

Edit: Just to be clear, the pipes are only to illustrate that I can achieve uniqueness after only 3 characters.  The result of the formula/method should be an array of equal length with only the shortest strings derived from the given set, in this case, the first three chars only.  Imagine that I want to use these in a URL, and that I can't have any ambiguity, but still want to be able to reference the same records as if I used the full string in each case.

**EDIT2:** Actually... as I think about it, no need for a result array, only an integer, the min length required in characters.

Comment: Not certain interpret Question correctly. How are characters to left of pipe character derived? Are the characters to left of pipe character to be derived from characters to right of pipe character?

Comment: @guest271314 check for example the `428` if you look at the second last, you'll see that it starts with `42`, so all the values are only unique when you use 3 chars...  the pipe only shows _when_ the values start being unique (note that I'm not the op)

Comment: @FirstOne Still not following where `428` is derived from?

Comment: Add an auto-increment column to the table and dispense with the use of UUIDs for foreign key references.

Comment: It's not derived from anything. The original value is `42807082e1f445e79501bebfa87396af`.. the op just added `|` to show where to look (where it starts being unique when comparing all the values from the set) - try for yourself.. first, check with 1 char.. it will repeat `4`, `0` and `1`.. with 2 chars.. it will repeat `42`.. with 3 chars, they are all unique @guest271314

Comment: @FirstOne Would uniqueness be between each of the thirty-two character sets?

Comment: @guest271314 I think the uniqueness should be between each **item** in the set, not each char in the item (you can see that there is a `011` in there)... The op should confirm that, though.

Comment: @FirstOne Agreed. Given a function which returns a thirty-two character unique set, could `.slice(0, 3)`, be called on each set, be used to return expected result?

Comment: @guest271314  The resulting set should be an array of the shortest possible substrings, such that if I used them in a URL to reference a record, it would still be entirely unique

Comment: @guest271314 I'd say yeah, but the op is asking for a _prettier_ way of achieving that without loops (they seem to be looking for a formula). Besides, it seems that not always the condition will be met with 3 chars

Comment: @oucil Did I get everything correctly until now? xD (This comment will self destruct in 30..29..28)

Comment: @FirstOne  That's correct, this is a short example, consider that the length of the sample array could be anything, I'm assuming deminishing returns the larger the set, but I imagine it would still work to a good degree on moderate sets, given the right formula

Comment: @oucil _"The resulting set should be an array of the shortest possible substrings"_ The `.length` of the set could range from two to thirty-two? You should be able to call `.slice(from, n)` on the thirty-two character unique string; where `from` is a random starting index less than `str.length + n` and `n` being the default or random `.length` of the expected shortened random string

Comment: @guest271314  Actually could range from a length of 1 if the set is less then 16 items (considering these are hex), to a max of 32.

Comment: Side-question, do you need the order? Can they be rearranged?

Comment: @FirstOne Order is not important.

Comment: @guest271314 Changed the desired result slightly, don't need an array, really just need the length value.

Comment: @oucil Have you tried checking `.slice(0, 3)` called on each set, then compared results?

Comment: @guest271314  How would I know to only slice 3?  That would only work in this example, not if cardinality required say 5 for instance in a larger set.

Comment: @oucil Perhaps still not gathering expected result, here? You could create an object, set object name to first `n` characters of string, or another set of `n` consecutive characters within string,  set value of object to entire string; reference string using name at object

Comment: @guest271314 Basically how short can I make these strings without making any ambiguous.... via formula.  FirstOne has the array solution I alluded to below, and while there might be ways to optimize, I figured it would come down to a nested loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to create some codes to achieve that. Take a look:

- **Code 1:**

```
function check_un($array){
    $arr = $array;
    $len = 1;

    $tmp = array();

    while (list($key, $value) = each($arr)) {
        $v = substr($value, 0, $len);
        if (isset($tmp[$v])) {
            $tmp = array();
            $len++;
            reset($arr); // start again
        }
        $tmp[$v] = true;
    }
    $tmp = array_keys($tmp);
    array_shift($tmp);
    return $tmp;
}
```

Basically, the previous code checks if given substring put as key is already set - meaning it's duplicated. That way, it goes to the beginning of the array and starts checking again with more letters.

---

- **Code 2:** *(smaller, but slower)*

```
function check_un($array){
    $array = array_values($array);
    $len = 1;
    $tmp = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($array[0]); $i++){
        if( count(array_unique( $tmp = array_map(function($v) use($len){ return substr($v, 0, $len); }, $array ) )) != count($array) ){
            $len++;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
    return $tmp; // this was set in the array_map part
}
```

Basically, the previous code checks if the quantity of unique elements of a given substring length is the same as the quantity of the original array. That way, if there are any duplicates, the quantity will be smaller, meaning that we need to use more positions.

---

*There used to be a code 3 (the first I tried), but it's only available in the edit history.*

---

You can test them with this:

```
$values = array(
    '42807082e1f445e79501bebfa87396af',
    '7230785bffaf4747865c202dd0924c7f',
    'b65634be909d4e5590aa0cdc97251eef',
    '3c4d94c683624d75a273e3186ec65b78',
    '09ebd42af0404bcf90413e11c5b40fbb',
    '011004743d65466dae8a9a6bc814ef4b',
    '1f1889e04e3a453fbf57521de0a70b60',
    '1ac44707af8d4681875171ad47c61037',
    '42f7a6236deb4a9ead32ab2e816d73a3',
    '83afe22086064eec87704127622b8165'
    //,'42807082e1f445e795aaaaaaaaaaaaa' // add this to test with more letters
);

$val = check_un($values);
```

---

The result (for both cases):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 428
    [1] => 723
    [2] => b65
    [3] => 3c4
    [4] => 09e
    [5] => 011
    [6] => 1f1
    [7] => 1ac
    [8] => 42f
    [9] => 83a
)
```

See them in action here:

- [Code 1](https://eval.in/610872);
- [Code 2](https://eval.in/610871).

---

You can change the returned value to get only the `$len` variable.

Comment: **Benchmarks**: Each method was run 10 times against 10k UUID's generated fresh for each iteration, then averaged. Times are in seconds. **Code 1** (Low|Avg|High): 0.01338 | **0.02279** | 0.03211 **Code 2** (Low|Avg|High): 0.66395 | **0.73791** | 0.84190 Code 1 as you can see was substantially faster!  When Code 1 was run against 50k uuid's 10x, the average was 0.13199!!!

Comment: @oucil code 2 does too many 'unnecessary' operations - I was just trying to make it smaller ^^ -, that's why it's more intensive. I just tested with 1kk times that set from the question and code 1 won by almost 3 seconds (total 14.8s on code 1) xD...

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize `Array.prototype.reduce()`, `Object.hasOwnProperty()` recursion; create an object to store values of unique character set, set object name to first two characters if name is not a property of object, else set first `n` characters until each property in object is unique

```js
var arr = ["42807082e1f445e79501bebfa87396af " 
           , "7230785bffaf4747865c202dd0924c7f" 
           , "b65634be909d4e5590aa0cdc97251eef" 
           , "3c4d94c683624d75a273e3186ec65b78"   
           , "09ebd42af0404bcf90413e11c5b40fbb" 
           , "011004743d65466dae8a9a6bc814ef4b" 
           , "1f1889e04e3a453fbf57521de0a70b60" 
           , "1ac44707af8d4681875171ad47c61037" 
           , "42f7a6236deb4a9ead32ab2e816d73a3" 
           , "83afe22086064eec87704127622b8165"];

var obj = {};

arr.reduce((o, uuid) => {
  var n = 1;
  (function re(key) {
    var curr = uuid.slice(0, key);
    if (!o.hasOwnProperty(curr)) {
      o[curr] = uuid;
    } else {
      re(key + 1)
    }
  }(n))
  return obj
}, obj);

console.log(obj, "arr length:", arr.length
           , "obj keys length:", Object.keys(obj).length);
```

Comment: Good try, but in the result set you're generating, if I were to use "4" for instance, it's ambiguous since it will also match the start of "42".  In order to ensure I chose the correct "4", I'd have to re-run this every time I referenced an ID to ensure I targeted the correct match.  The only way to avoid the ambiguity is to ensure that all of the reduced ID's are the same length.

Comment: @oucil _"The resulting set should be an array of the shortest possible substrings"_ , _"Actually could range from a length of 1"_ `4` is not ambiguous. Property values of object are unique. Once `4` is set as a property name, `4` alone cannot be used again to set a property name at object. That is, unless requirement is for minimum length string as reference, and not any length unique string as reference. Approach begins at `1`, and only moves to `2` when character at index `0` of previous string has been used as a property name

Comment: It may not be totally clear, but I'm not storing the shorter ID's since they'll need to be able to grow as more records are added to the set, so there's no mapping to reference.  So I will still have to do a wildcard query where I only know the start of the ID.  Since I know the ID would be unique at three chars in my example, I only need to provide those three chars to identify the proper record.  If I only use the first char, even though it's unique in your result set, it is ambiguous in actual real life use.

Comment: @oucil In that instance, calling `.slice(0, 3)` should return expected result

Comment: But we don't know that we only need three chars, what if we need 4 chars to be unique?  What I'm asking for is the formula that tells me I need 3... or 4.... or 8 chars.

Comment: @oucil The approach at IIFE within `.reduce()` is a possible formula. That is, store a temporary reference to a unique property, even if not used in application, if property exists within object call function until property is found which is unique. You could call `delete obj` at conclusion of process if references are not necessary. You could adjust `n` to `3` if expected result is minimum `.length` of `3` characters.